# Apply a function using another array how a argument in a pandas.Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

Have some way to apply a function in a `pandas.Series` using different values of another `pandas.Series`? I know that have the `pandas.Series.apply()`, but I need something like that:

```
array1 = pandas.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
array2 = pandas.Series([5, 5, 6, 0])

def func(x, y):
    return x+y

print(array1.apply(func, args = array2))


Out:
    0 6
    1 7
    2 9
    3 4
```

In other words, I need apply a function in a `pandas.DataFrame` column by I need use another column of same `pandas.DataFrame`. Using the same function `func`:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 5, 6, 0]})
df['c'] = df['a'].apply(func, args = df['b'])

print(df)


Out:
       a   b   c
    0  1   5   6
    1  2   5   7
    2  3   6   9
    3  4   0   4
```

Thank you!

I need use the apply because I use multiprocessing like pandarallel, so I just change apply() for parallel_apply(), someone know a way to do it? Use multiprocessing with operations that use two columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add columns from two dataframes then instead of

```
print(array1.apply(func, args = array2))
```

you can use

```
print(func(array1, array2))                                                                                                                                                               
0    6
1    7
2    9
3    4
```

If you want to add two columns of the same dataframe, you can do that simply in the following way:

```
df['c'] = func(df['a'], df['b']) 

print(df) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                           
   a  b  c
0  1  5  6
1  2  5  7
2  3  6  9
3  4  0  4
```

Comment: I need use the apply because I use multiprocessing like pandarallel, so I just change apply() for parallel_apply(), have some way to do it with that you said? I just use multiprocesing using two columns of a pandas.DataFrame()

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case you can just use:

```
df['c'] = df['a'] + df['c']
```

and for the principal function you use `Numpy` like in this example

```
df['c'] = numpy.exp(df['a']) + df['b']
```